# Does Selenium Python execute a program as scheduled in Windows or not?

Tags: python, windows, selenium, schedule

I am not sure how to phrase this question (does a tree falling in the forest make a sound if there's no one there to hear it?) but I have a simple program that visits several websites through a selenium loop, opening each url in a new tab.

I know the program works fine when I execute it and watch it work. When that happens, the program opens the tabs as instructed, then leaves them open for me to check that everything worked fine, then it sends me an email to let me know that the program has run.

Now my problem is that I have scheduled this task in Windows, and I receive the email when the program executes, but when this happens and I check my browser I don't see any tabs left open, as I usually see after the program has run.

So my question is/are: does Selenium have some code-only mode that executes the programs in the background and goes to the places I indicated it to go, without opening the tabs if I am not using the browser at the time? Could it be possible that the program is running and reaching the end -thus sending me the email- but did not open the tabs and thus it is not working when I schedule it to work and I am not at the computer or the computer is on standby (I have scheduled it to wake the computer to execute the program)

Is there anything I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: Did you close the webdriver after finished the job?

Comment: No, I did not. Should I? Would that make a difference?

Comment: If you quit the webdriver, it will close the browser. The difference is if you never quit the webdriver, the schedule will create new browser every time it executes scripts and it might be error if you have too many browser processes. Could you show your your code?